# How to add a contacts app like modal view (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, modal-dialog, edit

I'm looking for a tutorial (video or written) explaining how to create the iOS contacts app and especially the "add" modal view.

So far I made my way through to *believe* that the iOS contacts app would be made using static table view cells but I'm not sure if that's a) right and b) still state of the art as almost all Youtube tutorials regarding static table view cells are more than 2 or 3 years old. Is there anything I'm missing?

Disclaimer: I'm learning to code using Xcode and Swift for a few months now, having taken 3 online courses but all sample apps are rather basic apps without much design and functionality or not in that way that I'd need them for my app idea (add and edit via modal view). Please bear with me as I think as a newbie I just don't know the right search expression to find these on say Youtube.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Try this pod, https://github.com/chrisladd/CGLAlphabetizer/ 
This might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

> So far I made my way through to believe that the iOS contacts app
> would be made using static table view cells but I'm not sure if that's
> a) right

Static tableView is literally for static data. I checked the add modal screen of iOS contacts app, and the data there are very dynamic. So you won't be able to use static tableView for that.

So proceed with the dynamic tableView. However it would definitely require quite a lot of work if you would jump into that quite advanced UX. Another approach for adding a data, in an easier way, is to push a new screen for adding new contact, and then pop it when done. If you really want the iOS contacts app's UX, you may search on `tableView begin/end updates`.

> and b) still state of the art as almost all Youtube tutorials
> regarding static table view cells are more than 2 or 3 years old. Is
> there anything I'm missing?

Someitmes there's no problem with old tutorials. They can still help. But be aware of **deprecated** stuff they are trying to teach.

Comment: Thanks Glenn! I'm not afraid of the fact that "it would definitely require quite a lot of work if you would jump into that quite advanced UX". I mean, I'm not silly in that I know how complex the whole topic is especially for rookies like me, but the way I learn is simply: Show me everything I would need to know in my career so that I *then* know where I got to dive into for the respective issue.Thanks again for your reply! I'll dive into dynamic tableView then!

Answer (score 0):

If you are new in swift and xcode, so i recommend to learn swift5 and SwiftUI.
we are using storyBoards but in SwiftUI every things had change.
It is new and it will grow so fast.
https://www.udemy.com/course/ios-13-app-development-bootcamp/
this is not about contact app, but you can use this toturial for your goal

Comment: Hi iman, That's one of the courses I took. It's great and dives deep into various things but what all courses are missing is a in-depth tutorial of implementing a complex user interface with all several controllers, tabs, views and so on. As all modules aim to create different apps, there's nothing like module 4 builds on module 3 design wise. I like how each module builds upon the previous in terms of code, though. It would we great to have that building ONE app that grows and grows design wise - if that makes sense.

Comment: Oh and regarding SwiftUI: That would be the next stage but I think to start with it's easier to focus on "the real code" first and separate that from the design to avoid too much confusion